# pandas intervals: list length not matching dataframe length

Tags: python, pandas, list, iteration, intervals

given a column of intervals in a dataframe, I am checking if every single cell is equal to any of the elements contained in 'cat_list'. Every time this condition is true, the list 'inter_group' is filled with the element of 'n_list' with the same  index as the corresponding item in 'cat_list'. Since this df column contains some 'nan' values, I included an 'elif' clause.

Since the column contains 418 cells, I expect 'inter_group' to contain exactly the same number of elements but at the end of the iteration, the items contained in this list are 436 which I find very strange.
Where is the mistake and how to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Interval

inter_1=[Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(64.084, 72.042, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(72.042, 80.0, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), nan, Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), nan, Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right')]

df1=pd.DataFrame()


df1['inter_1']=inter_1

n_list=[0.6666666666666666, 0.41304347826086957, 0.3559322033898305, 0.33815028901734107, 0.4406779661016949, 0.34285714285714286, 0.4666666666666667, 0.375, 0.0, 0.5]
cat_list=[Interval(24.294, 32.252, closed='right'), Interval(16.336, 24.294, closed='right'), Interval(32.252, 40.21, closed='right'), Interval(40.21, 48.168, closed='right'), Interval(0.34, 8.378, closed='right'), Interval(8.378, 16.336, closed='right'), Interval(48.168, 56.126, closed='right'), Interval(56.126, 64.084, closed='right'), Interval(64.084, 72.042, closed='right'), Interval(72.042, 80.0, closed='right')]
inter_group=[]

for i in df1.inter_1:
    for j in cat_list:
        if i == (j):
            inter_group.append(n_list[cat_list.index(j)])
        elif i is np.nan:
            inter_group.append('nan')
print (len(inter_group))    #prints 436
print(len(df1['inter_1']))  #prints 418
print(len(inter_1))         #prints 418
```

Comment: This code will not work, because `Interval` is not defined :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, may you please provide an example ?

Comment: do you mean importing libraries ? If this is what you mean, I just edited my code